# Posting form inside a dialog to server using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

Let's say I have this **form** inside a **dialog**

```
<div id = "add-users">
   <form>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1">Jim<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2">Will
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
   </form>
</div>
```

When the submit button is clicked, is it possible to post the form using ajax? I don't want the whole page to post, just the dialog.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Give an Id to the submit button so that we can use that for jQuery selection later.

```
<input type="submit" id="ajaxSubmit" value="Add">
```

Now in javascript, listen for the submit button click and get the form and serialize it and send it to your action method.

```
$(function(){

   $("#ajaxSubmit").click(function(e){
      var _this=$(this);
      e.preventDefault();
      var _form=_this.closest("form");
      $.post("@Url.Action("Create","User")",_form.seriazlize(),function(result){
            //do something with the result
      });
  });

});
```

Assuming your action method parameter is good to receive the serialized form.

Comment: Can u give an example of a good candidate method that would receive the serialized form? It's not to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can Serialize your form and send to controller using AJAX.

View File **

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
var myform = $('form');
var fd = myform.serialize();
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
         url: '@Url.Content("~/Controller/Action")',
         data: fd });
```

Comment: The only problem is that there is already another form on the view. Maybe jQuery will be confused

Comment: you can define a ID for the form. And than you change $('form') to $('#formid')